# Is saying that search have a θ(1+a) complexity in hash table ( with chaining ) implying that it is also θ(a)?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable, complexity-theory, execution-time, clrs

I am looking at these snippets from [CLRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms):

Description of the hash table search time:

[image: CLRS description of hash table search time when collisions are solved with chaining]

Definition of  as /:

[image: CLRS definition of a (n/m) n being the number of keys effectively stored and m the size of the hashtable]

Explanation of θ ( removing constant factors and only keeping the order of growth ):

[image: CLRS explanation of θ ( removing constant factors and only keeping the order of growth )]

I do not understand this usage of the theta notation. We define the load factor  as /,  being the number of elements stored in the hash table and  being the number of cases in the hash table. So if we write θ(1+) this is exactly like if he write θ(1+/).

And θ(1+/) is by definition the set of functions  such there exist positive constants <sub><sub>1</sub></sub>, <sub><sub>2</sub></sub> and <sub><sub>0</sub></sub> such that:

0 ≤ <sub><sub>1</sub></sub>(1+/) ≤ () ≤ <sub><sub>2</sub></sub>(1+/) for any  ≥ <sub><sub>0</sub></sub>

Which seems to be included in θ(), the set of functions  such there exist positive constants <sub><sub>1</sub></sub>, <sub><sub>2</sub></sub> and <sub><sub>0</sub></sub> such that:

0 ≤ <sub><sub>1</sub></sub> ≤ () ≤ <sub><sub>2</sub></sub> for any  ≥ <sub><sub>0</sub></sub>

Moreover, there are two possibilities, either  is a constant, either it is not.
If  is a constant, θ(1+) is like writing θ() if I am not wrong.
If  is not a constant it means it depends on , so θ(1+) is like writing θ() again ( because constants don't matter when you have a function and try to use the θ notation as the 3<sup>rd</sup> quote says ).

So in any possible case we could/should have written θ() instead of θ(1+), couldn't we?

I don't understand why there is a `1+` before the

Answer (score 0):

> either  is a constant, either it is not. If  is a constant, θ(1+) is like writing θ() if I am not wrong. If  is not a constant it means it depends on , so θ(1+) is like writing θ() again [...] So in any possible case we could/should have write θ() instead of θ(1+), couldn't we ? I don't understand why there is a 1+ before the

Your reasoning is correct, but a few remarks:

If  is a positive constant we could also write θ(1+) as θ(1), which is more simplified than θ(), but you are right that θ(1+) can also be written as θ() in that case.

In general, you can indeed simplify θ(1+) to θ(), except for one obscure case:

When the hash stores no keys at all, then both  and  are zero. It is not stated in your document, but if this case needs to be covered, then / [is undefined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548/explanation-of-method-for-showing-that-frac00-is-undefined). If in that case  is defined to be zero, then we still have a problem, because then θ() = θ(0), which would mean there is **no** work at all. This is not true, because even when a hash table is empty, it costs time to determine that a key is not in it, i.e. O(1).

I think it might be because of this boundary case that the author preferred not to simplify θ(1+) to just θ().

Comment: Hello, thank you a lot for your answer. I think I do now understand better but when you explain : "When the hash stores no keys at all, then both  and  are zero.", in fact you don't even need m to be 0, just n right ? Because if n = 0 then a = 0 so if we only write θ() the problem appears too. By the way, since a = n/m, if we assume that n and m can't be 0, writing θ(1+) is the same as θ()  but is it the same than θ(n) in this case please ? Thank you by advance for your precious help

Comment: Yes, it depends on how "slots" is defined. I took the point of view that an empty hash table has no slots, and so when  would be zero, then it would follow that  would be zero too. It however the definition of slots allows  to be non-zero even when  is zero, then the argument for having `1+` is even more evident. As to the second question, again, that depends on the definition of slots. If the number of slots is completely unrelated to , then we cannot exclude it from the expression.